# Sass and libraries for theming

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm looking at creating a custom "theme" for my application, I'm currently pulling in the materialize library to do so, but I'd like to be able to easily generate new themes later on in the future using Sass.

Currently, materialize generates colors using this:

```
$colors: (
  "materialize-red": $materialize-red,
  "red": $red,
  "pink": $pink,
  "purple": $purple,
  "deep-purple": $deep-purple,
  "indigo": $indigo,
  "blue": $blue,
  "light-blue": $light-blue,
  "cyan": $cyan,
  "teal": $teal,
  "green": $green,
  "light-green": $light-green,
  "lime": $lime,
  "yellow": $yellow,
  "amber": $amber,
  "orange": $orange,
  "deep-orange": $deep-orange,
  "brown": $brown,
  "blue-grey": $blue-grey,
  "grey": $grey,
  "shades": $shades
);


// Color Classes

@each $color_name, $color in $colors {
  @each $color_type, $color_value in $color {
    @if $color_type == "base" {
      .#{$color_name} {
        background-color: $color_value !important;
      }
      .#{$color_name}-text {
        color: $color_value !important;
      }
    }
    @else {
      .#{$color_name}.#{$color_type} {
        background-color: $color_value !important;
      }
      .#{$color_name}-text.text-#{$color_type} {
        color: $color_value !important;
```

Ideally I'd like to hook into that before the colors are generated and add my own such as:

```
 @import "public/bower_components/materialize/sass/materialize";

 $custom-colors: (
 "titleAccent":$blue
 );
 map-merge($colors,$custom-colors);

 .backgroundColor {
   @extend .blue-grey.lighten-4;
 }
```

I think it's important to note that the .backgroundColor works, but unfortunately does then not allow me to lighten it as I would see fit later on.

Am I going about this all wrong?
Thanks!

Edit:
Not a duplicate of "Extends gives weird results"
If I can help it, I don't even want to extend, I want to add to a map.

Comment: @cimmanon Did you even read my question? I don't want to write my own css as is in the "Duplicate" you marked.

Comment: 1) The provided code does not compile.  2) I don't know how you think you're going to be able to use the lighten function without access to the colors themselves.

Comment: 1) It's not supposed to, read it. 2) Read it. I don't use the lighten function. At all. It's a css class. Read it.

Comment: I don't know how else I am supposed to interpret "I think it's important to note that the .backgroundColor works" as meaning anything other than "this code compiles without error" and "but unfortunately does then not allow me to lighten it as I would see fit later on" as "I want to use the lighten function".

Comment: "add my own such as:" - I never said it would compile, hell, I even ask for an example of adding to an already existing map - That's the whole point of this question. Nevertheless - Please remove the duplication, it is not a duplicate of that question in the slightest.

Comment: I don't think a user can undo their Mjolnir. @ThomasNairn, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You want to import Materialize.css, but change the color values *during* import, not after? Are you asking how to make those changes on the fly? Or how to generate colors? Or something else?

Comment: @ThomasNairn So what does theming have to do with your actual question?  If what you wanted to know was how to merge mappings, you sure have a roundabout way of asking.

Comment: @TylerH apologies, I'll make adjustments to the question. That was actually constructive. Thanks. I'm really trying to ask, what's the best way of using the already generated classes to create custom classes that allow me to change them easily later on.